# Find Common element in two lists in java and add them to starting position in list with remaining element of second list using java8

Tags: java, list, sorting, stream

I have two lists containing names. The first list `l1` has **selected** names, and the second list `l2` has **all** the names.

*Example:*

```
List<String> l1 = {"en", "cu", "eu"};
List<String> l2 = {"ch", "cu", "en", "eu", "pe"};
```

All the elements in `l1` always exist in `l2`.

I want to obtain the output where all the common names are placed at the beginning followed by the remaining names, and I need them to be sorted in the ascending order.
Like this:

```
output ->  {cu, en, eu, ch, pe};
```

What I was trying to do I've shown below, but don't getting the idea that how to place common elements at the starting position (2nd list is already sorted) and place the remaining elements after the common elements

```
List<String> common = l2.stream().filter(l2::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why is `cu` present twice in your output? Shouldn't the second one by `ch`?

Comment: @Thiyagu my bad , now you can see edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to sort the elements from the second list `l2` by placing the values that are present in the first list `l1` at the beginning, and both part should be sorted in the alphabetical order.

You need to define a custom `Comparator` for that purpose. Since Java 8 the recommended way to create a Comparator is to use static factory methods like [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)).

While implementing the Comparator, firstly we need to check if a particular value is present in the first list and order the elements by the result of this check (reminder: natural ordering of `boolean` values is `false` -> `true`). And since `contains()` on a list is costful (it does iteration over the list under the hood and therefore runs in **O(n)**) it would be performance-wise to dump the data from the first list into a `HashSet` and perform checks against this Set.

The in order to sort both parts of the list alphabetically, we need can chain the second comparator by applying [`Comparator.thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)) and providing `Comparator.naturalOrder()` as the argument.

Here's how it might be implemented:

```
List<String> l1 = List.of("en", "cu", "eu");
List<String> l2 = List.of("ch", "cu", "en", "eu", "pe");
        
// output ->  {cu,en,eu,cu,pe};
        
Set<String> toCheck = new HashSet<>(l1);
Comparator<String> comparator =
    Comparator.<String,Boolean>comparing(toCheck::contains).reversed()
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        
List<String> sorted = l2.stream()
    .sorted(comparator)
    .toList(); // for Java 16 or collect(Collectors.toList())
    
System.out.println(sorted);
```

*Output:*

```
[cu, en, eu, ch, pe]
```

Comment: @Alexandar thanks for the reponse , but i can get similer answer by only using Comparator<String> comparator =
    Comparator.<String,Boolean>comparing(toCheck::contains).reversed() so why we are making chain ?

Comment: @jitendravarshney You need to apply `Comparator.naturalOrder()` to ensure that result would be sorted in ascending order as required. You're getting identical result only because elements in your sample `l2` appear in alphabetical order. [See what would happen](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/BFD) if we shuffle values in `l2` and drop `thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()).` So, you can remove the second part of the Comparator only if you would need to partition the list (in this case, elements in both parts of the resulting list would appear according to their encounter order in `l2`).